# Contour shows dots rather than a curve when retrieving it from the list, but shows the curve otherwise

Tags: python, opencv

I'm finding the contour of a thresholded image and drawing it like so:

```
self.disc_contour = cv2.findContours(self.thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1] 
cv2.drawContours(self.original_image, self.disc_contour, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
```

and I get the contour as desired:

(ignore the inner circle. The outer part is the contour in context)

[image]

But if I change `self.disc_contour` in the drawContour function to `self.disc_contour[0]` I get the following result:

[image]

What could be the reason?

Comment: The second parameter should be a list of contours -- i.e. a list of lists of points. I think that `self.disc_contour[0]` is only a single contour, and it seems like openCV treats each point as separate curve. Try `[self.disc_contour[0]]` instead. (or `self.disc_contour[0:1]`).

Comment: Another thing i've just noticed -- `cv2.findContours` returns a pair: `(contours, hierarchy)`. You take the second element (index 1), which is the hiearchy, but treat it as the contour list? Oh, or perhaps you're using CV 3.x rather than 2.4.x ? It seems that the API changed slightly. Could you clarify this and add a working example to let us reproduce it?

Comment: @DanMašek, your solution worked. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Also, yes, I'm using Opencv 3.1. Can you please explain why your solution works? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*NB: Specific to OpenCV 3.x*

The second result from `cv2.findContours` is a **list of contours**.
The second parameter of `cv.drawContours` should be a **list of contours**.

A contour is represented as a list (or array) of points. Each point is a list of coordinates.

There are multiple ways how to draw only a single contour:

```
import cv2

src_img = cv2.imread("blob.png")
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(src_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

contours = cv2.findContours(gray_img, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1]

print(contours)

# Choose one:    

# Draw only first contour from the list
cv2.drawContours(src_img, contours, 0, (0,255,0), 2)
# Pass only the first contour (v1)
cv2.drawContours(src_img, [contours[0]], -1, (0,255,0), 2)
# Pass only the first contour (v2)
cv2.drawContours(src_img, contours[0:1], -1, (0,255,0), 2)


cv2.imshow("Contour", src_img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Sample input image:

[image]

When we inspect the result of `cv2.findContours`, the reason why you were seeing dots becomes apparent -- there are 4 levels of nesting.

```
[
    array([
        [[ 95,  61]], # Point 0
        [[ 94,  62]], # Point 1
        [[ 93,  62]],
        ... <snip> ...
        [[ 98,  61]],
        [[ 97,  61]],
        [[ 96,  61]]
    ]) # Contour 0
]
```

According to the definitions at the beginning of this answer, we can see that the points in this case are wrapped in an additional list, e.g. `[[ 98,  61]]`. OpenCV apparently deals with this correctly - I suppose this was intended as a feature.

If we remove the outer list by using only the first element of `contours`, we effectively turn each point into a separate contour containing a single point.

```
array([
    [
        [ 95,  61] # Point 0
    ], # Contour 0
    [
        [ 94,  62] # Point 0
    ], # Contour 1
    ... and so on
])
```

Comment: Is `[self.disc_contour[0]]` a way of preserving coordinates while also removing the outer list? Because I just noticed, that while the contour is no longer drawn dotted, points are still missing. Is there a way I can retrieve all the coordinates of a contour?

Comment: The contour will remain unchanged. It makes a new list containing only the first element of the original list. Element in this case being one contour. What's `len(self.disc_contour)` in that scenario? What if you select the contour to draw using the third parameter to `cv2.drawContours`? Is it possible that some contours overlap? How did you figure out you're missing some points?

Comment: I figured out I'm missing some points because there's no same y coordinate as the centroid, or even x coordinate for that matter. Also, `len(self.disc_contour)` is 1.

Comment: In that case `self.disc_contour == [self.disc_contour[0]]`. I don't think there's anything guaranteeing that a contour would contain a point with the same x or y coordinate as the centroid.

Comment: No, I mean if I find a centroid,  (x, y), there's obviously a point on the contour where the y coordinate matches (right above and below the centroid), and a point where the x coordinate matches (to the left and right of the centroid)

Comment: Oh, right, I see now -- it seems as if `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` is not taking effect, and you're expecting to see all those border points, my bad.

Comment: Right, great catch. Is there an alternative for `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` so I can get all the points? Or is there a way I can obtain all the coordinates of the contour that is drawn - that is the complete contour, rather than the dotted one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107773/discussion-between-dan-masek-and-stack).