# How to draw filled contour from numpy array of points using cv2.drawContours?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-image

How to draw filled contour from numpy array of points using `cv2.drawContours`

For some reason this code draw single points and not filled contour:

```
ctr = np.array(pts).reshape((-1, 1, 2)).astype(np.int32)
mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, ctr, contourIdx=-1, color=1, thickness=-1)
```

Using skimage I can do it like:

```
from skimage.draw import polygon

mask = mask.astype(np.uint8)

rr, cc = polygon(pts[:, 1], pts[:, 0], mask.shape)
mask[rr, cc] = 1

mask = mask.astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311398/contour-shows-dots-rather-than-a-curve-when-retrieving-it-from-the-list-but-sho/36315105#36315105) out

Comment: you can also use the fillPoly of OpenCV if you are drawing close contours

Comment: @DanMašek not sure what format `contours` after `cv2.findContours` have, I have numpy array of `np.float32` with shape `[n_pts,2]`

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote that... but try drawing `[ctr]` instead of `ctr`? When it's drawing just dots, it's missing one level of hierarchy in the nested arrays, and treats each point as a separate contour.