# Trouble filling contours with opencv

Tags: opencv, contour

I have a list of contours which I extracted using cv.drawContours and I am trying to fill the contour in. I wanted to use cv.drawContours but nothing is working.

I tried using thickness = -1, thickness = cv.FILLED, or even using a different function, cv.fillPoly. All three of these methods do not alter my image at all. I've also tried to input a list of contours into cv.drawContours as well as looping through the contours individually. The cv.drawContours function works when thickness is any other number. I've also tried explicitly saying what the parameters are (image = testim, contours = cnts[j]), or not saying what they are at all.

```
cnts, hierarchy = cv.findContours(img, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        
for j in np.arange(len(cnts)):
    cv.drawContours(testim, cnts[j], -1, color = (255, 0, 0), thickness = -1)
```

Comment: Does this help? `cv.drawContours(testim, cnts[j], 0, color = (255, 0, 0), thickness = -1)`

Comment: The second parameter should be a list of contours, not a single contour. You select which one to draw using the third parameter. IIRC the way you called it, it causes each individual point of the contour to be treated as a full contour, and it just draws a bunch of points.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contour shows dots rather than a curve when retrieving it from the list, but shows the curve otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311398/contour-shows-dots-rather-than-a-curve-when-retrieving-it-from-the-list-but-sho)

Comment: @toyotaSupra I'd be surprised, you still feeding it a single contour instead of a list of them. You want `cv.drawContours(testim, cnts, j, ...`

Comment: @Dan Mašek. I wasn't aware of `numpy`. I was looking at looping.

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you so much, it worked!